# .NET Core Hosting Runtime and SDK on Windows Server 2012 for running dotnet commands

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Running `ASP.NET Core` websites under IIS on a `Windows Server 2012` where we installed the `.NET Core 2.2.7 Hosting Runtime` installer.

With Azure Release pipline we want to run our migrations using commands but we got a message saying:

```
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

So basically we also need to install the .NET Core SDK, but will this work when having the Hosting runtime installed? Can we drop the hosting runtime and only install the SDK? I guess not because I thoughed the SDK is for developing.

How to perform dotnet operations on staging and production environments?

**UPDATE**

To be more clearly about I am asking, I want to run my `Entity Framework Migrations` on the environment after the deploy process. So basically running the command `dotnet ef database update -v` after pushing the files on the staging and production enviroment. So not in the `Azure container` but on the real destination webserver.

Comment: Have you ensure inside the azure-release-pipeline.yml file that the sdk is installed?

Comment: Nope. Microsoft deliberately separates the bits in the runtime and the SDK, so you do need both and no alternative. But what exactly do you want to run there for "our migrations"?

Comment: Its not very common to use the dotnet commands to perform migrations and similar stuff. Most of the commands only work on projects (i.e. require tools be installed via csproj or globally installed), not on published artefacts (created via `dotnet publish` command). And trying to run project in container is just non-sense. If you want perform some migration, generate some output scripts (`dotnet ef migrations script`), this will create an SQL file (in case of SQL/mysql providers) which you can run with the native db tools or (the preferred approach), use `context.Database.Migrate()`

Comment: View my update about some extra details and clearification.

Comment: You need the SDK installed on the destination server. I don't think it will create any issues because the Hosting and Runtime bundle is already installed. But, my personal preference will be using a 'SQL script' to update the tables on the production servers. The EF Migrations are really helpful, to get the changes (included by others) into your local during the development phase but not a good idea for production scenarios.

Comment: @Thangadurai thanks for the input. I now have added an extra step in the build process to generate the SQL scripts to be deployed to the environments.